# Laravel + Dingo + JWT + cors and OPTIONS method

Tags: php, laravel-5, cors, jwt, dingo-api

On my Laravel installation, I have set up `Dingo API` along with `JWT-Auth` by tymondesigns and `Laravel-cors` by barryvdh.

This is the process of logging in and retrieving data from the front end (which is hosted on a different server):

1. `POST` credentials to the `API`
2. receive `JWT` token, which is then stored in `localStorage` with `Bearer` key in front. After this point, the interceptor automatically gets and sets the Authorization header with `JWT` token.
3. `POST` request is sent to `/users/me`, which is just a route to retrieve the user data. The user data comes with `username, email, permissions and messages` at the moment. `messages` is an `Eloquent` model where `User::class` basically `hasMany(Message::class)`. By the way, the method that retrieves the user data, reads the user using `$user = JWT::parseToken()->authenticate();` and then I'm using `Dingo`'s `$this->response()->item($user, new SelfTransformer());` to send the data back.

So at this point everything seems to be working fine. The user is logged in, the user object is populated with all the necessary stuff, and the messages table is populated with messages.

I am paginating the messages, so at the moment I am receiving just 1 message at a time.

Now the issue is that after this point (after the user object is retrieved), if I make another request, let's say to the  `/users/me?messages=2` to retrieve the second page of messages, I get the following error:
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I get the same error if I try to log out as well.

I even get the same error if I try to register with already registered user.

So it feels like every single time there is an exception thrown in Laravel, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is no longer set.

This is my cors configuration:

```
return [
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |

     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'Accept', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Origin'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    'exposedHeaders' => ['Authorization'],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

If I use Postman, it all works fine.

Also, I noticed that in my network tab, there are 2 requests being set all the time. One has method set to `OPTIONS` and the second one is the actual request...

I am getting depressed...

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.
In your `app/Http/routes.php` put this at the top and see.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With,  Content-Type, Accept");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

That's pre-flight request, I think it's fine